# Htaccess redirect query string with file name? wordpress interfering

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, query-string

I've got an issue with my htaccess redirects not working as expected.

The new website I'm working on is using logical slugs, whereas the old site has outdated IDs etc.

Old url for news item: https://mccann-ltd.co.uk/news.php?pID=87
New url for news item: https://mccann-ltd.co.uk/news/achilles-link-up-accredited-qualified-supplier-to-the-uk-rail-industry

I updated the htaccess with these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} pID=87(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) /news/achilles-link-up-accredited-qualified-supplier-to-the-uk-rail-industry [R=301,L]
```

Which worked, however when I switched to the new wordpress setup, these redirects stopped working. Is it something to do with wordpress's rule? i.e.:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Or could it be that I need to include the file name with my rule i.e. adding news.php:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} news.php?pID=87(.*)$
```

Any help would be appreciated as I'm unsure how to move forward.

Thanks

Comment: Did you do your redirects _before_ the WP stuff?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, good shout @CBroe that's worked, however now it's appending pID which means the page won't load (https://mccann-ltd.co.uk/news/achilles-link-up-accredited-qualified-supplier-to-the-uk-rail-industry?pID=87)

Comment: Add a question mark to the end of the substitution URL (`/news/…-industry?`), or use the `QSD` flag.

Comment: Literally just tried that and it worked! thanks for your help :) for others with a similar issue - adding ? to the rule and including before wordpress rules is what allowed it to work. -
(RewriteRule (.*) /news/achilles-link-up-accredited-qualified-supplier-to-the-uk-rail-industry? [R=301,L])